Controlling Manipulate using a mouse-over wheel scroll
Can I get Manipulateto allow me, once the plot appears, to hover my mouse over the plot and scroll my mouse wheel to vary the parameter $a$? Currently I need to drag the bar manually.
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]


I'm looking to use it for loading chess game .gif files i.e. to create a notebook of opening variations, so I need lots of mouse over access to many animations to explore openings quickly.

Last time I looked into this, it didn't really seem possible (not even with some very desperate hacky attempts). Things might have changed of course, or I could have missed something, but I wouldn't be surprised if what you want is still not feasible

Is there a way of controlling it with the keyboard?

this approach may not be desperate, though I think that if it's possible it's very hacky and don't worth to try. (I use it for a similar problem)

Will try this now, thanks!

Using the hack suggested by @andre314, you can use
DynamicModule[{x = {0.1, 0.}, a = 1}, 
 Pane[Pane[Dynamic[Plot[Sin[x  (1 + a  x)], {x, 0, 7}], {x, 0, 6}], 
   ImageSize -> {Full, 1100}, AppearanceElements -> None, 
   Scrollbars -> None], ImageSize -> {Full, 1000}, 
  AppearanceElements -> None  Scrollbars -> {False, True}, 
  ScrollPosition -> Dynamic[x, Function[If[#[[2]] >= x[[2]], a--, a++];
     x[[2]] = Mod[x[[2]] + 0.001, 0.1, 0.1];]]]]

which can produce different curves on mouse scrolling

(a few mouse scrolls...)

and for the chess example, save e.g. this chess gif as chessgame.gif, then try
frames = Import["chessgame.gif"];
(*This gives periodic boundary conditions to the scrolling*)
cycle[a_, frames_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   If[Mod[a, Length@frames] > 0, 
    out = frames[[Mod[a, Length@frames]]]]; 
   If[Mod[a, Length@frames] == 0, 
    out = frames[[Mod[a, Length@frames] + 1]]]; out];
(*This gives the animation itself*)
DynamicModule[{x = {0.1, 0.}, a = 1}, 
 Pane[Pane[Dynamic[cycle[a, frames]], ImageSize -> {Full, 1100}, 
   AppearanceElements -> None, Scrollbars -> None], 
  ImageSize -> {Full, 1000}, 
  AppearanceElements -> None  Scrollbars -> {False, True}, 
  ScrollPosition -> Dynamic[x, Function[If[#[[2]] >= x[[2]], a--, a++];
     x[[2]] = Mod[x[[2]] + 0.001, 0.1, 0.1];]]]]

which gives a scrolling chess animation

(a few mouse scrolls...)

